# ¿Cómo utilizar un método de una clase externa, el cual dicha clase utiliza métodos de la clase original en C++?

Tags: c++, array, método, class, compilacion

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual consiste en resolver una ecuación 2x2, para ello utilicé el método de Cramer, el problema no es cómo solucionarlo, sino que me arroja un error al momento de ejecutarlo, y sospecho que es porque utilicé métodos de la clase Matriz dentro de la clase Vector (y dicha clase Vector utiliza métodos de la clase Matriz), en cambio dicho error no me sucede si el Vector utiliza métodos de la clase Matriz pero la Matriz no utiliza métodos ningún método externo, me salen los siguientes errores:

```
clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main Matrix2d.cpp Vector2d.cpp main.cpp
In file included from Matrix2d.cpp:1:
In file included from ./Matrix2d.h:3:
./Vector2d.h:48:19: error: unknown type name 'Matrix2d'
   void resolver(Matrix2d aMat);
                 ^
1 error generated.
In file included from Vector2d.cpp:1:
In file included from ./Vector2d.h:1:
In file included from ./Matrix2d.h:3:
./Vector2d.h:48:19: error: unknown type name 'Matrix2d'
   void resolver(Matrix2d aMat);
                 ^
Vector2d.cpp:31:16: error: out-of-line definition of 'resolver'
     does not match any declaration in 'Vector2d'
void Vector2d::resolver(Matrix2d aMat){
              ^~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
In file included from main.cpp:2:
In file included from ./Vector2d.h:1:
In file included from ./Matrix2d.h:3:
./Vector2d.h:48:19: error: unknown type name 'Matrix2d'
   void resolver(Matrix2d aMat);
                 ^
1 error generated.
compiler exit status 1
```

O como se muestra en la foto (no me deja utilizar para nada el método): [image: Noten que no me deja utilizar este método bajo ningún motivo]

Cambiando el código de otra forma pude notar con total seguridad que el problema está en el método  `resolver`, porque dicho error sólo está ahí si el método resolver (el cual está en la clase vector) utiliza métodos de la clase matriz, y dicha clase matriz utiliza métodos de la clase vector.
A continuación les muestro mi código:

En el Vector.h:

```
#include "Matrix2d.h"
#ifndef VECTOR2D_H_
#define VECTOR2D_H_
/**
 * Esta clase implementa métodos que simulan un vector de 2 dimensiones (2x1)
 * Septiembre 30 de 2020
 */
class Vector2d{
  private: // Atributos
    double vectorPrincipal[2]; // vector 2x1
  public:
    /**
     * Constructor 
     * @return crea el objeto Vector2d
     */
    Vector2d(); 
    /**
     * Destructor
     * @return destruye el objeto Vector2d
     */
    ~Vector2d();
    /**
     * <setComponente0>: <> --> <void>
     * Obtiene el componente [0] del vector
     * @return vectorPrincipal[0]
     */
    double getComponente0();
    /**
     * <getComponente1>: <> --> <void>
     * Obtiene el componente [1] del vector
     * @return vectorPrincipal[1]
     */
    double getComponente1();
    /**
     * <getVectorPrincipal>: <> --> <void>
     * Inserta los valores del vector 2x1
     */
    void setVectorPrincipal();
    /**
     * <resolver>: <Vector2d> <Matrix2d> --> <void>
     * Resuelve una ecuación lineal de 2 incógnitas
     * con 2 variables utilizando el método de Cramer
     * @example
     *  vectorRespuestaEjemplo = {3, 1}   // (Asumiendo que MatrizEjemplo es ={{3,2,11},{4,1,13}})
     * vectorRespuestaEjemplo.resolver(vectorVariable,matrizVariable)
     */
    void resolver(Vector2d aVec, Matrix2d aMat);
    /**
     * <imprimirVector>: <> --> <void>
     * Imprime el vector 2x1
     */
    void imprimirVector();
};
#endif
```

En el Vector.cpp:

```
#include "Vector2d.h"
#include "Matrix2d.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Vector2d::Vector2d(){
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    vectorPrincipal[i]=0;
  }
}

Vector2d::~Vector2d(){}

double Vector2d::getComponente0(){
  return vectorPrincipal[0];
} 

double Vector2d::getComponente1(){
  return vectorPrincipal[1];
}

void Vector2d::setVectorPrincipal(){
  double datosEntrada;
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    cout<<"Digite el componente ["<<i<<"] del vector: ";
    cin>>datosEntrada;
    vectorPrincipal[i]=datosEntrada;
  }
}
// En el método de resolver se utilizará el método de Cramer

// AQUÍ ES DONDE ESTÁ EL ERROR!!!!!!

void Vector2d::resolver(Vector2d aVec, Matrix2d aMat){
  cout<<"hola"<<endl;
  // Con tal que pueda imprimir Hola es suficiente.
   /*
  double detS=aMat.getDeterminanteS(aVec);
  double detX=aMat.getDeterminanteX(aVec);
  double detY=aMat.getDeterminanteY(aVec);

  vectorPrincipal[0]=(detX/detS);
  vectorPrincipal[1]=(detY/detS);
 */ 
} 

void Vector2d::imprimirVector(){
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    cout<<"[ "<<vectorPrincipal[i]<<" ]"<<endl;
  }
}
```

En la Matriz.h:

```
#ifndef MATRIX2D_H_
#define MATRIX2D_H_
#include "Vector2d.h"
/**
 * Esta clase implementa métodos que simulan una matriz 
 * aumentada de dos ecuaciones lineales
 * Septiembre 30 de 2020
 */
class Matrix2d{
  private: // Atributos
    double matrixPrincipal[2][2]; // Matriz 2x3
    double determinanteX, determinanteY, determinanteS; // Las determinantes para utilizar el método de Cramer
  public:
    /**
     * Constructor 
     * @return crea el objeto Matrix2d
     */
    Matrix2d(); 
    /**
     * Destructor
     * @return destruye el objeto Matrix2d
     */
    ~Matrix2d();
    /**
     * <getDeterminanteX>: <> --> <double>
     * Obtiene el valor del atributo determinanteX
     * @return determinanteX 
     */
    double getDeterminanteX(Vector2d aVec);
    /**
     * <getDeterminanteY>: <> --> <double>
     * Obtiene el valor del atributo determinanteY
     * @return determinanteY
     */
    double getDeterminanteY(Vector2d aVec);
    /**
     * <getDeterminanteS>: <> --> <double>
     * Obtiene el valor del atributo determinanteS
     * @return determinanteS
     */
    double getDeterminanteS(Vector2d aVec);
    /**
     * <setMatrixPrincipal: <> --> <void>
     * Inserta los valores de la matriz 2x3
     */
    void setMatrixPrincipal();
    /**
     * <imprimirMatrixIncognitas>: <> --> <void>
     * Imprime la matriz de la parte de las incógnitas
     */
    void imprimirMatrix();
};

#endif
```

En la Matriz.cpp:

```
#include "Matrix2d.h"
#include "Vector2d.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Matrix2d::Matrix2d(){
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
    matrixPrincipal[i][j]=0;
    }
  }
  determinanteS=0;
  determinanteX=0;
  determinanteY=0; 
}

Matrix2d::~Matrix2d(){}

double Matrix2d::getDeterminanteX(Vector2d aVec){
  determinanteX=(aVec.getComponente0()*matrixPrincipal[1][1])-(matrixPrincipal[0][1]*aVec.getComponente1());
  return determinanteX;
}

double Matrix2d::getDeterminanteY(Vector2d aVec){
  determinanteY=(matrixPrincipal[0][0]*aVec.getComponente1())-(matrixPrincipal[1][0]*aVec.getComponente0());
  return determinanteY;
}

double Matrix2d::getDeterminanteS(Vector2d aVec){
  determinanteS=(matrixPrincipal[0][0]*matrixPrincipal[1][1])-(matrixPrincipal[1][0]*matrixPrincipal[0][1]);
  return determinanteS;
}


void Matrix2d::setMatrixPrincipal(){
  // i son las filas y j las columnas
  double datosEntrada;
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
      cin>>datosEntrada;
    matrixPrincipal[i][j]=datosEntrada;
    }
  }
}

void Matrix2d::imprimirMatrix(){ 
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    cout<<"[ ";
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
      cout<<matrixPrincipal[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"]"<<endl;
  }
}
```

En el main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector2d.h"
#include "Matrix2d.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout<<"Con tal de que el programa compile bien es suficiente"<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Si necesitan comprender mejor cómo debería de funcionar correctamente el programa, hice otro código con una pequeña modificación, el cual la clase Vector utiliza métodos de la clase Matriz, pero la clase Matriz NO UTILIZA métodos de la clase : https://repl.it/repls/NonstopPiercingLists#main.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por un lado tenemos esto en `Vector2d.h`

```
#include "Matrix2d.h"
```

Y por otro lado tenemos esto otro en `Matrix2d.h`

```
#include "Vector2d.h"
```

Como ves, ambas cabeceras se incluyen mutuamente y eso es algo que funciona mal en C++. Vamos a seguir la traza del error para entender el problema:

```
In file included from Matrix2d.cpp:1:
In file included from ./Matrix2d.h:3:
./Vector2d.h:48:19: error: unknown type name 'Matrix2d'
   void resolver(Matrix2d aMat);
```

Los includes son equivalentes a reemplazar la directiva por el contenido del archivo, tal cual esté.

Así pues, el error dice que `Matrix2d.cpp` incluye a `Matrix2d.h`, es decir:

`Matrix2d.cpp` quedaría así:

```
// Esto reemplaza el include ...
#ifndef MATRIX2D_H_
#define MATRIX2D_H_
#include "Vector2d.h"
class Matrix2d
{
  // ...
};
#endif // MATRIX2D_H_
/// ... hasta aqui

// Y después el resto de Matrix2d.cpp
#include "Vector2d.h"
// ...
```

Entonces se procesa el include de `Vector2d.h`, quedando el archivo así:

```
#ifndef MATRIX2D_H_
#define MATRIX2D_H_
#include "Matrix2d.h"
#ifndef VECTOR2D_H_
#define VECTOR2D_H_
class Vector2d
{
  // ...
};
#endif // VECTOR2D_H_

class Matrix2d
{
  // ...
};
#endif // MATRIX2D_H_

// Y después el resto de Matrix2d.cpp
#include "Vector2d.h"
// ...
```

Vaya, ha aparecido otro Matrix2d.h ...

```
#ifndef MATRIX2D_H_
#define MATRIX2D_H_
#ifndef MATRIX2D_H_ // <<--- ojo
// ...
#endif // MATRIX2D_H_
#ifndef VECTOR2D_H_
#define VECTOR2D_H_
class Vector2d
{
  // ...
};
#endif // VECTOR2D_H_
class Matrix2d
{
  // ...
};
#endif // MATRIX2D_H_

// Y después el resto de Matrix2d.cpp
#include "Vector2d.h"
// ...
```

Al reemplazar `Matrix2d.h` por segunda vez, la directiva `#ifndef` hará que se cargue un archivo vacío, ya que el símbolo ya se encuentra definido. Las guardas se hacen precisamente para evitar que un mismo símbolo aparezca declarado varias veces.

Así pues, el archivo `Matrix2d.cpp`, una vez procesados las directivas, quedará así:

```
class Vector2d 
{
  void resolver(Vector2d aVec, Matrix2d aMat);
};
class Matrix2d
{
  // ...
};

// Y después el resto de Matrix2d.cpp
```

Y aquí es donde se ve el error... aparece la función `resolver`, la cual hace uso de un parámetro de tipo `Matrix2d`... pero ese tipo **no está definido aún**.

¿Cómo se arregla esto? Usando *declaration forward*. Las declaraciones solo sirven para que el compilador pueda conocer el tamaño que debe reservar para los diferentes objetos y llamadas.

La declaración de la función `resolver`, no necesita saber cuáles son los métodos de `Matrix2d`, sino únicamente necesita saber que el tipo existe y esa información se puede proveer mediante los *declaration forward*:

```
#ifndef VECTOR2D_H_
#define VECTOR2D_H_

class Matrix2d; // <<--- declaration forward

class Vector2d
{
  void resolver(Vector2d aVec, Matrix2d aMat);
};
```

Usar *declaration forward* permite desacoplar clases. Piensa que al usar includes, los cambios que haces en un archivo se propagan a todos aquellos que lo incluyan (y por extensión a todos los archivos que incluyan a estos últimos y así). Esto hace que un cambio tonto, como añadir una línea a un archivo, implique recompilar cientos o miles de archivos ... solo por abusar de los includes.

Los *declaration forward*  solo son útiles cuando no es necesario conocer el tamaño del objeto, es decir, si `Vector2d` tuviese una variable miembro que fuese de tipo `Matrix2d` entonces no se podría usar un *declaration forward* porque entonces el compilador sería incapaz de calcular el tamaño que van a ocupar los objetos de tipo `Vector2d`:

```
class Matrix2d;

class Vector2d
{
  Matrix2d matrix; // <<--- ERROR
};
```

Sin embargo sí podríamos usar un *declaration forward* si la variable miembro fuese un puntero:

```
class Matrix2d;

class Vector2d
{
  Matrix2d* matrix; // <<--- OK
};
```

Esto es así porque los punteros tienen un tamaño fijo que viene determinado por la arquitectura del sistema (32 bits, 64 bits, ...).

Los *declaration forward* tienen mucha más miga, no tiene sentido explicarla toda aquí porque la respuesta sería demasiado extensa.

Así pues, resumiendo, tu programa funcionará simplemente reemplazando los includes de las cabeceras por sendos *declaration forward*:

Así quedaría `Matrix2d.h`

```
#ifndef MATRIX2D_H_
#define MATRIX2D_H_
class Vector2d;

// ...
```

Y así `Vector2d.h`

```
#ifndef VECTOR2D_H_
#define VECTOR2D_H_
class Matrix2d;

// ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, mi código ahora sí funciona y tu explicación fue muy entendible.
Ahora entiendo del por qué el error, no se pueden referenciar recíprocamente las clases entre sí porque luego generaría en el error que explicaste.